# PHP Почему in_array возвращает true

Tags: php

Вот весь код: `in_array(0, ['text', 'caption'])`
Возвращает true. Версия PHP 7.2, в чем причина?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ответ нашел тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23735773/5909792).

Функция [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php) по умолчанию не использует строгое сравнение, а без этого произойдет странное (в версии до 8, начиная с 8 версии был доработан алгоритм нестрого сравнения и с ним код ниже вернет `false`):

```
var_dump(0 == 'text');
// bool(true)
```

Нужно включить строго сравнение в [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php):

```
var_dump(in_array(0, ['text', 'caption']));
// bool(true)
 
var_dump(in_array(0, ['text', 'caption'], true));
// bool(false)
```

Comment: а почему в php8 работает нормально? потому что там по умолчанию строгое?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, причина в улучшении алгоритма сравнения. Нашел тут https://habr.com/ru/post/526220/ в пункте **6 Адекватное приведение строки в число (Saner string to number comparisons)**: `Это происходит потому, что при нестрогом == сравнении строки с числом, строка приводится к числу, то есть, например (int)"foobar" даёт 0. В PHP8, напротив, сравнивает строку и число как числа только если строка представляет собой число. Иначе, число будет конвертировано в строку, и будет производится строковое сравнение.`

Answer (score 1):

Установи строгое сравнение

```
in_array(0, ['text', 'caption'], true)
```

Comment: вопрос не как победить, а в чём причина